# Best practice for organizing and publishing 1000 PostGis Tables into Geoserver Datastore

Tags: geoserver

I have about 1000 tables that are spatially enabled within a Postgis database.  They are all within a single database and divided between about 20 users and schemas.  I have a single user called gis that has access to every table.

I am looking into using the geoserver rest api to programatically publish all the tables.  However, I'm not sure the best practice in creating a datastore, group, etc...

My assummuption is that every feature will be used equally and I would like to be able to maybe group each schema separately.

I'm not sure the best approach
My thoughts are that I would create a separate datastore for each schema/user and then publish all tables within this datastore.  I would also then create a layer group with all of these features.   Is this possible and does it make sense?

As an alternative Should/Can  I create a single datastore and publish All 1000 tables within the single datastore.....and would I be able to create say 20 layer groups from this datastore.

Essentially I'm looking for best practice for organizing 1000 features in a postgis database spread across about 20 schemas.